# Converting a pandas dataframe to JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert a pandas DataFrame to JSON file. Following image shows my data:
[Screenshot of the dataset from Ms. excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5qcL.png)

I am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

os.chdir("G:\\My Drive\\LEC dashboard\\EnergyPlus simulation files\\DEC\\Ahmedabad\\Adaptive set point\\CSV")

df = pd.read_csv('Adap_40-_0_0.1_1.5_0.6.csv')
df2 = df.filter(like = '[C](Hourly)',axis =1)
df3 = df.filter(like = '[C](Hourly:ON)',axis =1)
df4 = df.filter(like = '[%](Hourly)',axis =1)
df5 = df.filter(like = '[%](Hourly:ON)',axis =1)

df6 = pd.concat([df2,df3,df4,df5],axis=1)
df6.to_json("123.json",orient='columns')
```

I the output, I am getting a dictionary in of values. However, I need a list as value.

The output I am getting: [The JSON output I am getting by using above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWH5N.png)

The out put that is desired: [The output that is desired.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2r13.png)

I have tried different orientations of json but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other ways of doing this but one way is this.

```
import json
test = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(test.to_dict(orient='list'), f)
```

Result file will look like this `'{"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}'`

Comment: So you are saying that i need to convert my dataframe to a dictionary?

Comment: one workaround is to use other JSON library, for example, rapidjson[link repo](https://pypi.org/project/python-rapidjson/) to write the data. At least in my local benchmark is was way faster than the default json library.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function of pandas called to_json:

```
df.to_json(r'Path_to_file\file_name.json')
```

Take a look at the documentation if you need more specifics: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html